# Gnuplot not reading YYYY-mm-dd correctly and getting "more % conversions than data arguments" (Xcode C++)

Tags: c++, xcode, gnuplot

I am trying to plot data from a .dat file that I create. My main issue is that gnuplot does not seem to understand the date format (it is being retrieved online by using cURL - along with the rest of the data) 
the other error I get is from Xcode mentioning that there are more % conversions than arguments as well as invalid conversion specifier 'Y'. Below is the line of code that the issue is in.

```
fprintf(gnuplotPipe,"set xdata time; set timefmt \"%Y-%m-%d\"; set format x \"%Y-%m-%d\"; plot \"file.dat\" using 1:3 with linespoints \n", data);
```

Ultimately, I would like to plot price (third column) vs date (first column), however, I get a graph with only year vs price so it is a vertical line by the year but the points indicate the correct prices. On the X-axis it displays `Y-m-0` at every interval. I also forgot to mention that I am getting an error with the x range saying that it is empty (Line 0).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Seems to me you need to escape those % characters.  (You might be better off placing your Gnuplot string in a separate string, rather than as a printf format string.  Then the % characters wouldn't cause trouble.)

Comment: I escaped them like so: `set timefmt \"\%Y-\%m-\%d\";` however I still get the same result. I have a feeling that I may not be reading the file correctly?

Comment: If you're still getting the same compiler errors then you didn't escape them correctly.  (IIRC, to escape % in a format string you double it up, vs using backslash.)

Comment: But like I said, probably better to not put it in a format string, but make it a string parm.

Comment: Thank you so much for this! `%%` before the specifier worked like a charm!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape the % characters, or else not put your Gnuplot string in a printf format string.  To escape % characters in a printf format string you double them up -- %% -- rather than use a backslash.